# How to make select from react ant searchable

Tags: reactjs, select, antd

I have to select from react form. Options are taken from query. By default options from antd are searchable, but I can't search mine. Any help would be great.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
  const options = !loading
    ? data.something.map((user) => {
      return { value: user.id, label: `${user.code} - ${user.name}`, user };
    })
    : [];

  <Select
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    placeholder="..."
    onChange={...}
    options={options}
    loading={loading}
  />
```

Comment: Could you please show what you do by `onChange`?

Comment: const [user, setUser] = useState();

Comment: did you try onSearch prop in select?

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka yes, that was my first try. But sadly it doesn't make it searchable in my case

Comment: show in your example how you are making request to server from query

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka I got data from graphql query, so I have object there